# how to create app insight dashboard through ARM

Tags: azure, azure-devops

can we create app insight dashboard through ARM Template. I need to create app insight with dashboard through ARM.

Comment: Can I confirm that could you create the dashboard successfully by ARM per my below sample? If it is help for you, appreciate for [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which others could know whether it is worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course sure.

You can follow this doc firstly to generate your ARM template: [Programmatically create Azure Dashboards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-dashboards-create-programmatically?WT.mc_id=none-stackoverflow-nepeters). For me, I am using this [sample structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-dashboards-create-programmatically?WT.mc_id=none-stackoverflow-nepeters#template-representation-of-our-example-dashboard).

Here I show you the simple sample of mine:

**Template.json:**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "dashboardName": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "lenses": {
          "0": {
            "order": 0,
            "parts": {
              "0": {
                "position": {
                  "x": 0,
                  "y": 0,
                  "colSpan": 2,
                  "rowSpan": 1
                },
                "metadata": {
                  "inputs": [
                    {
                      "name": "id",
                      "value": "/subscriptions/daaeef3e-*****-f9d072825/resourcegroups/{resource group name}/providers/microsoft.insights/components/mer1210" #my application insight
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "Version",
                      "value": "1.0"
                    }
                  ],
                  "type": "Extension/AppInsightsExtension/PartType/AspNetOverviewPinnedPart",
                  "asset": {
                    "idInputName": "id",
                    "type": "ApplicationInsights"
                  },
                  "defaultMenuItemId": "overview"
                }
              },
              "1": {
                "position": {
                  "x": 2,
                  "y": 0,
                  "colSpan": 1,
                  "rowSpan": 1
                },
                "metadata": {
                  "inputs": [
                    {
                      "name": "ComponentId",
                      "value": {
                        "Name": "mer1210",
                        "SubscriptionId": "daaeef3e-******-b3df9d072825",
                        "ResourceGroup": "{resource group name}"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "Version",
                      "value": "1.0"
                    }
                  ],
                  "type": "Extension/AppInsightsExtension/PartType/ProactiveDetectionAsyncPart",
                  "asset": {
                    "idInputName": "ComponentId",
                    "type": "ApplicationInsights"
                  },
                  "defaultMenuItemId": "ProactiveDetection"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "metadata": {},
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01-preview",
      "type": "Microsoft.Portal/dashboards",
      "name": "[parameters('dashboardName')]",
      "location": "westus",
      "tags": {
        "hidden-title": "[parameters('dashboardName')]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

As what you see in the `Template.json` file, I just specified a parameter in it. And this template only point to one Azure resource: `mer1210` (my application insight).

So, next steps is assign value to my parameter `dashboardName`.

**Parameter.json:**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "dashboardName": {
      "value": "Merlin-12-10"
    }  
  }
}
```

---

See the deployed result on my side:

[image]

---

Just make a little changes based on my sample,  such as the `dashboard` name, the `metadata` that you want it shown in this dashboard.